# How to extract all .tgz files in subdirectories?

Tags: linux

I have a list of `*tgz` files in a `./main/` directory such as

```
$ tree -L 3
.
├── 191009-Grace_587_8G_R2
│   └── Grace_587_8G_R2
│       └── output.tgz
├── 191009-Grace_V0G_R2
│   └── Grace_V0G_R2
│       └── output.tgz
├── 191009-Grace_V8G_R2
│   └── Grace_V8G_R2
│       └── output.tgz
├── 191014-Grace_587_0G_R2
│   └── Grace_587_0G_R2
│       └── output.tgz
├── 191014-Grace_587_8G_R2
│   └── Grace_587_8G_R2
│       └── output.tgz
├── 191014-Grace_V0G_R2
│   └── Grace_V0G_R2
│       └── output.tgz
└── 191014-Grace_V8G_R2
    └── Grace_V8G_R2
        └── output.tgz
```

I am wondering how to extract them all together to the directory containing them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `tar`'s  `-C` / `--directory` option:

> `-C`, `--directory=DIR`
>     Change to DIR before performing any operations. This option is order-sensitive, i.e. it affects all options that follow.

```
for i in *-Grace_*/Grace_*/output.tgz; do 
  tar xzf "$i" --directory="${i%/*}"
done
```

The parameter expansion `${i%/*}` removes the filename from the path (like the `dirname` command). To extract the files to the `main` directory, remove the `--directory` option.

---

Using `find` with the `-execdir` option:

```
find . -type f -name 'output.tgz' -execdir tar xfz {} +
```